# What exactly is the definition of an evaluation oracle?

Tags: computational-complexity

What is the definition of an evaluation oracle in complexity theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine

Comment: Thanks! I have seen wikipedia, but I still don't understand what an evaluation oracle. In the paper I read I am trying to understand the following line: "Problem (2) can be solved and hence a Generalized Nash Equilibrium can be comptued in time that is polynomial in N, in <M,b,u> and in the number of calls of evaluation oracles" The last part is what I don't understand.